# after updating numpy, np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided gives error

Tags: python, numpy

I updated numpy from an older version, unfortunately I didn't check which one, to version 1.12.0.
I have a script which worked perfectly fine up to the update. It uses the following line of code:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as _ast

    raw_shp = _ast(raw, shape=sh, strides=stride).squeeze()
```

gives error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 102, in as_strided
      array = np.asarray(DummyArray(interface, base=x))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

What changed in _ast or np.asarray, to raise this error and what can I do to avoid it?

thanks for any hint

Comment: What is the value of `sh`?

Comment: it's (12501.0, 2692, 2, 4)

Comment: Make sure all the values in `sh` are actually integers, not floating point with integer values.  Either fix how `sh` is created (recommended), or do something like `shape=tuple(int(i) for i in sh)`.

Comment: I suspect `(12501, 2692, 2, 4)`, consisting of all integers, would work.

Comment: no :-( still same error message..

Comment: stride has also some float values, this may have solved the problem

Comment: In general the newer `numpy` versions are pickier about using floats when indexing.  In the past it may have automatically truncated floats; but that's not always predictable.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, my code is up and running again. 
I posted a summary of your answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently newer numpy versions are pickier about using floats when indexing.
Converting all floating point numbers for indexing to integers solved the problem 
Like Warren Weckesser said:
Make sure all the values in sh are actually integers, not floating point with integer values. Either fix how sh is created (recommended), or do something like shape=tuple(int(i) for i in sh).